# WPF: Button wont change its Grid.Column

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, menu, grid

I want to create a Menu with a Button on the right and one on the left. In the center of the Menu i want a MenuItem. Everything works so far except for the Button_forward which i want to put in GridColumn 2. No matter what i try, the Button stays in GridColumn 0. I can display everything in GridColumn 2 except that Button.

This is what it's supposed to look lik

+------------------------------------+
| Button    |     MenuItem      |    Button |
+------------------------------------+

```
<Menu DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="30" Background="Gainsboro" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Menu.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid ShowGridLines="True" x:Name="Grid1">        
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Menu.ItemsPanel>
    <Button Height="20"  Width="40" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="Button_backward"     Click="Button_backward_Click" IsEnabled="False">
        <Image Source="..\Resources\leftarrow.png"/>
    </Button>

    <MenuItem Grid.Column="1" Height="20" >
         <TextBox Text="Test"></TextBox>
    </MenuItem>
    <Button Grid.Column="2" Height="20"  Width="40" x:Name="Button_forward" Click="Button_forward_Click" IsEnabled="False">
        <Image Source="..\Resources\rightarrow.png"/>
    </Button>
    </Menu>
```

If i put the Button in a MenuItem, it is displayed correctly in Column 2

```
    <MenuItem Grid.Column="2">
        <Button Height="20"  Width="40" x:Name="Button_forward" Click="Button_forward_Click" IsEnabled="False">
            <Image Source="..\Resources\rightarrow.png"/>
        </Button>
    </MenuItem>
```

How can i display the Button in the second column?

Thanks!

Comment: in my c# code i only enable the buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this is understandable,

The way the `Menu` control works is if you do not provide a `MenuItem` and provide something like a `Button` directly, it will wrap that `Button` in a `MenuItem` internally(thus making your `Grid.Column` specification on the `Button` useless as far as the menu's `ItemsPanel` is concerned).

You can check this behavior with [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) such as:

[image]

As you can see the `Button` is wrapped in a `MenuItem` and since it does not have a `Grid.Column` specified on it, it gets placed at column 0 as default thus giving you your issue.

**Solution:**

As you guessed, wrap your `Button` in a `MenuItem` (thus giving it the appropriate column in the definition which the system wont change later)

**or**

Style a `MenuItem` to look like your `Button` and use that directly.

**or**

Use a different Layout control like `StackPanel` or sorts that don't impose this requirement